# Android Change src img in webview

Tags: android, image, webview, android-webview

I have a webview in which i load a content (news) from a Webservice.

The only problem is, my image in this content has src like this :

```
<img src='images/myimage.png'>
```

and of course, in my webview i can't show this image.

So, how can i update the src of all my image ? (to add the correct url to show it)

I'm loading my content like this :

```
                String htmlNews = "<html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlContent;
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlNews, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: are these images located on the assets folder? try to put the images in the same location as your html file, not in a separate folder.

Comment: Lol no, the images are on my website.

Answer (score 0):

Put your **image** into the assets directory `eg: assets/img.png`

Then load your html with:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Reference your img like:

```
<img src="img.png">
```

You can also try

```
String data = "<body>" + "<img src=\"large_image.png\"/></body>";
```

w`ebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",data , "text/html", "utf-8",null);`

Answer (score 0):

Load Html file in Webview and put your image in asset folder and read that image file using Html.

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="abc.gif" width="50px" alt="Hello">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Now Load that Html file in Webview

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your html code like this:

```
String web = "<img src='images/myimage.png'>";
String replace = "src='";
String replaceWith = "src='http://example.com/";
String webParsed = web.replace(replace, replaceWith);
System.out.println(webParsed);
```

where http://example.com/ should be the prefix you want to add to the src tag.

Comment: thx for answer, but i found other thing more simple.. the html tag <base> :)

Answer (score 0):

I take the [@deveLost's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631775/android-change-src-img-in-webview#comment34474253_22635764) and I leave it here in order to get more attention.

There exists a [`<base>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) that defines the base URL, you don't have to intercept anything starting with / or relative to the path, the HTML client will automatically work on

```
val yourBaseUrl: String = ...
val originalContent: String = ...
val fixedContent = "<base href='$yourBaseUrl'>$originalContent"
webView.loadData(fixedContent, "text/html", "UTF-8")
```